# rsync from one server to other takes more space

Tags: rsync, github

I am trying to take the contents of an old Ubuntu server's `/backup` folder and `rsync` it over to a new Ubuntu server's `/backup` folder. The old server has 39G of a 50G drive used for the data.  I made `/backup` on the new serer 50G as well, but it filled up when I ran `rsync`.  I increased it to 100G and figured that would be overkill, but nope, it ran out too.

The `rysnc` command I used:

```
rsync -e ssh -avz myoldserver:/backups/* .
```

FYI the `/backups` is from a github backup command ghe-backup (not sure if that helps with response).

Comment: does removing the `*` from the rsync command solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe hard links are split into separate files. (Use the option -H to avoid that.)

Comment: There may be problems with loops caused by symbolic links.

Comment: You don't especially need the `-e ssh` option as `rsync uses `ssh` by default, it's useful if you're doing unusual stuff with the ssh connection like changing the port though.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [Storage Requirements](https://github.com/github/backup-utils#storage-requirements) section, `ghe-backup` uses [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link). A hard link is when one file is listed more than once, either under different names or in different directories. They look like two different files, but really the data is stored only once.

Rsync by default doesn't look for this, so it ends up copying the file completely each time it's listed. You need to add `-H` to your rsync options to tell rsync to look for this and handle it correctly. **Note**: doing this is much slower and often requires quite a bit of RAM, so be warned it may take longer than you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you, I had read about this -H option.  I vaguely remember the distinction of soflink versus hardlink, so I was not sure sure if this would apply to my situation or not anyway.

Comment: I just copied over 220G of data between two usb3 external hard disks using rsycn with -H option.  It took me 4 or 5 days of continuous running.

Answer (score 0):

use this command:

```
rsync -e ssh -avz myoldserver:/backups/ /backups
```

When you use an "*", it will not copy hidden (dot) files.
You can also you the extra option `--delete` to delete files on the destination, if they don't exists on the source.

Comment: Cool, I will try it with the --dry-run option (-n) to see how that goes

Comment: @user372429 Do _man rsync_ and check the Push and Pull actions.

Comment: dry run shows: sent 3,239,192 bytes  received 27,887,043 bytes  122,303.48 bytes/sec
total size is 106,160,081,929  speedup is 3,410.63 (DRY RUN)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [generator=3.1.1]

Comment: _some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors)_ 
Check for errors in the transfer list. Probably a permissions issue.

Comment: Removing the * did not seem to make a difference.  I ended up doing one subdirectory that came over at 82GB still although the original as mentioned is about half that size.  

I wonder if the fileystem on the Juno openstack is using storage that is compressed and the new Mitaka openstack is not.  Anyway, I am letting the github create the backups and as they roll off (I only keep 10 versions) the size of the filesystem is dropping to add more to the mystery.  I guess that might discount the idea that the compression is on though.